# Изменить select при изменении первого

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть один select:

```
<select id="one">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">One</option>
    <option value="three">One</option>
    <option value="four">One</option>
</select>
```

И есть второй select, идентичный первому.

```
<select id="two">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">One</option>
    <option value="three">One</option>
    <option value="four">One</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы когда в первом выбиралось некоторое значение, то автоматом выбиралось бы такое же значение во втором. Но если изменяем второй селект, то первый не изменяется.
Сделал вот так, но не совсем все верно

```
$('#one').change(function(){

            var val     = $("#one").val();

            $('#two option:selected').remove();
            $("#two option").each(function(){
                if($(this).val() == val){
                    var n = this.nodeName;  
                    $(n).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
            });
    });
```

В данном случае всем option присваивается selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#one').on('change', function(){
    $('two').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#auto').change(function () {
    var car = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

    $("#klass option").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == car){
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
});
```